# How to improve my ship trajectory prediction program using LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tf.keras

I want to predict the trajectory of a ship following a road. I train my model with 6 trajectories following the same road. Then I want to predict the trajectory of a 7th boat following the same road. To do it, I give to my model the previous moment to predict the next, the moment is constituted of (Latitude, Longitude, Speed, Course (angle)). My problem is that I can't manage to improve my performance and I don't have enough experience to know what to do.
(I used to MinMaxScaler(), to scale my data.)

For know my model is :

```
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=False, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_steps_in, n_features)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_steps_out))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(n_features, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='mse')
```

n_steps = 1; n_features = 4

Does anyone know how I can improve the model because I tried a lot of things and can't improve more.

The data are :

```
    Date                 MMSI        utm_LON     utm_LAT       SOG  COG
1   2021-01-08 10:46:00  351120000 383877.394473 3.722548e+06 11.1 -2.4609
2   2021-01-08 10:47:00  351120000 383532.277465 3.722545e+06 11.2 -2.4452
3   2021-01-08 10:48:00  351120000 383445.967732 3.722541e+06 11.2 -2.4617
4   2021-01-08 10:49:00  351120000 382606.283771 3.722538e+06 11.2 -2.4783
...
5175   2021-01-20 23:55:00  538007142 152085.925923 3.814797e+06 9.8  -2.1659
5176   2021-01-20 23:56:00  538007142 151756.324321 3.814898e+06 9.8  -2.1694    
5177   2021-01-20 23:57:00  538007142 151459.379307 3.814986e+06 9.8  -2.1746
5178   2021-01-20 23:58:00  538007142 151127.991170 3.815088e+06 9.8  -2.1799
```

In my input I only consider sorted data made of lon lat sog cog.
Thank you !

Comment: Did you do an analysis of like getting a mean track along a route and getting the deviation of individual ships based on that? How do you measure 'goodness of prediction' and how does that account for other external, yet untracked things like weather, tides and flow which inherently reduce predictability? I.e.: do you know that it *can* be improved?

Comment: The only thing I did is clustering in order to get a road based on my 6 ship trajectories. But I didn't do a mean track and don't really know how to do it. To measure my prediction I only compare the real track to my prediction. And to finish I don't have access to external thing such as weather. Thanks

Comment: Could you share some data? how many n_steps_in is there in the LSTM input?

Comment: There are 5 n_steps in the inputs to predict the 5 next values. Data are in the first question I updated it. thanks